# What does this source code from the Linux Kernel Do?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

```
    COMPAT_SYSCALL_DEFINE1(sysinfo, struct compat_sysinfo __user *, info){
struct sysinfo s;

do_sysinfo(&s);

/* Check to see if any memory value is too large for 32-bit and scale
 *  down if needed
 */
if (upper_32_bits(s.totalram) || upper_32_bits(s.totalswap)) {
    int bitcount = 0;

    while (s.mem_unit < PAGE_SIZE) {
        s.mem_unit <<= 1;
        bitcount++;
    }

    s.totalram >>= bitcount;
    s.freeram >>= bitcount;
    s.sharedram >>= bitcount;
    s.bufferram >>= bitcount;
    s.totalswap >>= bitcount;
    s.freeswap >>= bitcount;
    s.totalhigh >>= bitcount;
    s.freehigh >>= bitcount;
}

if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, info, sizeof(struct compat_sysinfo)) ||
    __put_user(s.uptime, &info->uptime) ||
    __put_user(s.loads[0], &info->loads[0]) ||
    __put_user(s.loads[1], &info->loads[1]) ||
    __put_user(s.loads[2], &info->loads[2]) ||
    __put_user(s.totalram, &info->totalram) ||
    __put_user(s.freeram, &info->freeram) ||
    __put_user(s.sharedram, &info->sharedram) ||
    __put_user(s.bufferram, &info->bufferram) ||
    __put_user(s.totalswap, &info->totalswap) ||
    __put_user(s.freeswap, &info->freeswap) ||
    __put_user(s.procs, &info->procs) ||
    __put_user(s.totalhigh, &info->totalhigh) ||
    __put_user(s.freehigh, &info->freehigh) ||
    __put_user(s.mem_unit, &info->mem_unit))
    return -EFAULT;

return 0;
    }
    #endif /* CONFIG_COMPAT */
```

I am confused as to what this code segment actually does. I understand that it does something with memory allocation, but if someone could explain to me what's going on in this code I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: ... It scales the values until they fit into 32 bits.

Comment: It doesn't really have *anything* to do with memory allocation. It is the implementation of the sysinfo system call, it just returns the memory and swap usage and such.

Comment: "In the above structure, sizes of the memory and swap fields are given as multiples of mem_unit bytes."

Answer (score 2):

The [`sysinfo`](https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/sysinfo.2.en.html) syscall fills in a structure with various system information. It is defined by `SYSCALL_DEFINE1(sysinfo, struct sysinfo __user *, info)`.

The `COMPAT_SYSCALL_DEFINE1` variant is for 32-bit code interacting with a 64-bit kernel. The return structure is defined with `long` values, which means 64-bit for 64-bit programs and 32-bit for 32-bit programs. The reported memory sizes are in multiples of `mem_unit`. If `totalram` or `totalswap` do not fit in a 32-bit value, and `mem_unit` is less than `PAGE_SIZE`, then it scales `mem_unit` by a power of 2 up to `PAGESIZE` and scales the rest of the memory values down by the same factor. Ideally, they now fit in 32-bit values, and by scaling this way, 32-bit programs still get a reasonably accurate view of system information. If not, there's no good way to return good values through the 32-bit API, too bad.

Note, at this time I think `mem_unit` is `PAGESIZE` to begin with, so this code probably doesn't do anything.